# Function is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, flutter

Insurance Model

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
import 'dart:convert';

class Insurance {
  final String? id;
  final String lifeInsurance;
  final String healthInsurance;
  final String microPension;
  const Insurance({
    this.id,
    required this.lifeInsurance,
    required this.healthInsurance,
    required this.microPension,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'lifeInsurance': lifeInsurance,
      'healthInsurance': healthInsurance,
      'microPension': microPension,
    };
  }

  factory Insurance.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Insurance(
      id: map['_id'] != null ? map['id'] as String : null,
      lifeInsurance: map['lifeInsurance'] as String,
      healthInsurance: map['healthInsurance'] as String,
      microPension: map['microPension'] as String,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Insurance.fromJson(String source) =>
      Insurance.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

Insurance Services

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:verdent/global_variable.dart';
import 'package:verdent/models/insurance.dart';
import 'package:verdent/providers/user_provider.dart';

class InsuranceServices {
  void addInsurance({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String lifeInsurance,
    required String healthInsurance,
    required String microPension,
  }) async {
    final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);

    try {
      Insurance insurance = Insurance(
        healthInsurance: healthInsurance,
        lifeInsurance: lifeInsurance,
        microPension: microPension,
      );

      http.Response res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('$uri/api/add-insurance'),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'x-auth-token': userProvider.user.token,
        },
        body: insurance.toJson(),
      );

      httpErrorHandling(
        response: res,
        context: context,
        onSuccess: () {
          showSnackBar(context, 'Your Insurance Detail Added Successfully!');
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

farmer_insurance

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:verdent/Forms/services/insurance_service.dart';

import '../../Dashboard/Home/Widgets/drawer.dart';

class Farmer_Insurance extends StatefulWidget {
  const Farmer_Insurance({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Farmer_Insurance> createState() => _Farmer_InsuranceState();
}

class _Farmer_InsuranceState extends State<Farmer_Insurance> {
  // static const String routeName = '/insurance';

  final _addInsuranceFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final InsuranceServices insuranceServices = InsuranceServices();
  List<String> yno = ['Yes', 'No'];
  String selectedvalue8 = 'Yes';
  String selectedvalue9 = 'Yes';
  String selectedvalue10 = 'Yes';

  void addInsurance() {
    insuranceServices.addInsurance(
      context: context,
      healthInsurance: selectedvalue8,
      lifeInsurance: selectedvalue9,
      microPension: selectedvalue10,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavigationDrawerWidget(),
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(235, 238, 239, 1.0),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: Builder(
            builder: (context) => InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.black,
                onTap: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                },
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.notes,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  size: 30,
                ))),
        title: const Text(
          "Insurance Details ",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
            child: InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.black,
                onTap: () {},
                child: Ink(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.notifications_outlined,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 30,
                    ))),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _addInsuranceFormKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 10.0, bottom: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          "Insurance Details ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 17,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      height: size.height / 2,
                      width: size.width / 1.12,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 20, right: 20, top: 20, bottom: 30),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: size.height / 70,
                          ),
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Life Insurance",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 17,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 150,
                                  height: 70,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                    child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: const Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 227, 242, 253),
                                              width: 2),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                        ),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 207, 234, 255),
                                              width: 2),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                        ),
                                        filled: true,
                                        fillColor: Colors.amber,
                                      ),
                                      hint: const Text("Select Options: "),
                                      value: selectedvalue8,
                                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                      iconSize: 24,
                                      isExpanded: true,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                      ),
                                      items: yno
                                          .map((String item) =>
                                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                                  value: item,
                                                  child: Text(item,
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 18))))
                                          .toList(),
                                      onChanged: (String? item) {
                                        setState(() => selectedvalue8 = item!);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: size.height / 70,
                          ),
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Health Insurance",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 17,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 150,
                                  height: 70,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                    child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: const Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 227, 242, 253),
                                              width: 2),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                        ),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 207, 234, 255),
                                              width: 2),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                        ),
                                        filled: true,
                                        fillColor: Colors.amber,
                                      ),
                                      hint: const Text("Select Options: "),
                                      value: selectedvalue9,
                                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                      iconSize: 24,
                                      isExpanded: true,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                                      items: yno
                                          .map((String item) =>
                                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                                  value: item,
                                                  child: Text(item,
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 18))))
                                          .toList(),
                                      onChanged: (String? item) {
                                        setState(() => selectedvalue9 = item!);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: size.height / 70,
                          ),
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Micro Pension",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 17,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 150,
                                  height: 70,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                    child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: const Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 227, 242, 253),
                                              width: 2),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                        ),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 207, 234, 255),
                                              width: 2),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                        ),
                                        filled: true,
                                        fillColor: Colors.amber,
                                      ),
                                      hint: const Text("Select Options: "),
                                      value: selectedvalue10,
                                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                      iconSize: 24,
                                      isExpanded: true,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                                      items: yno
                                          .map((String item) =>
                                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                                  value: item,
                                                  child: Text(item,
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 18))))
                                          .toList(),
                                      onChanged: (String? item) {
                                        setState(() => selectedvalue10 = item!);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: size.height / 70,
                          ),
                          MaterialButton(
                            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0))),
                            color: Colors.green,
                            highlightColor: Colors.white,
                            splashColor: Colors.amber,
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (_addInsuranceFormKey.currentState!
                                  .validate()) {
                                addInsurance();
                              }
                            },
                            child: const Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 50.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'SUBMIT',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15),
                                )),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Insurance.js

```
const express = require("express");
const insuranceRouter = express.Router();
const auth = require("../middlewares/auth");
const { Insurance } = require("../models/insurance_detail");

//Get all your products

insuranceRouter.post("/api/add-insurance", auth ,async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const { lifeInsurance, healthInsurance, microPension } = req.body;

    let insurance = new Insurance({
      lifeInsurance,
      healthInsurance,
      microPension
    });
    insurance = await insurance.save();
    res.json(insurance);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message });
  }
});

module.exports = insuranceRouter;
```

Showing this error when i try to upload my data on my database "Insurance is not a Constructor".I don't know why this error is showing I tried to add const in my Isurance model but same error is showing again and again please tell me how to solve this issue

Comment: What line is that error associated with?

Comment: thats what i unable to understatnd